# Do you think this kitten will have medium or short hair?

Tags: cats, new-pets

Thinking about getting this cutie but I live in higher elevation in Denver. Hoping for a medium hair cat! :)[image]

Comment: it has medium lenght fur,please take a look at the answers in the linked Q&A

Comment: If the animal will be an indoor cat and you don't run your thermostat unusually low, fur length doesn't matter much; short-furred cats are comfortable at roughly the same temperatures humans are. (I have caught mine shivering when the indoor temp was low enough to make me look for a sweater.)